# Is there any web mining Library in Node.js for sentiment analysis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, sentiment-analysis, web-mining

I am doing sentiment analysis in Javascript using Node.js. 
I am looking for web mining packages in Node to clean a web page.
Is there any built-in package for web mining in Node like we have in R tm.plugin.webmining Package?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are any high-quality web mining packages in Node.js.
The reason is sentiment analysis is a process, which uses lot of CPU. Processes with this type are blocked in Node.js event loop, so you should avoid them.

In Node.js world, for this type of task we use [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). With this solution, you don't block event loop in main process and have ability to use any tool for child process. R for example.